# R: I do not get P-Values for rmANOVA using aov()

Tags: r, statistics, data-science, analysis

I have tried to perform a two-way repeated-measures analysis, but I cannot get the p-values with my R code. Do you have any ideas about what is wrong?

```
myData.mean <- aggregate(main$ER,
                         by = list(main$PID, main$Mode, main$Task),
                         FUN = "mean")
colnames(myData.mean) <- c("PID12","Mode12","Task12","ER12")
myData.mean <- myData.mean %>% arrange(PID12)

stress.aov <- with(myData.mean,
                   aov(ER12 ~ Mode12 + Task12 + 
                         Error(PID12 / Mode12 * Task12)))
summary(stress.aov)
```

Do you have any ideas why this could be?
Thank you in advance for your answers! Of course, I am happy to answer any questions regarding the problem.

Comment: Hi @Paul Bäumer, could you please share your data using `dput(data)` with us so we can help you better?

Comment: @Quinten  I hope this helps. PID12 = Participant Number; Mode12 = Independent variable 1; Task12 = Independent Variable 2; ER12= Dependent variable
`structure(list(PID12 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Mode12 = c("V", 
"W", "V", "W", "V"), Task12 = c("CT", "MT", "CT", "MT", "CT"), 
    ER12 = c(2.33333333333333, 2, 0.333333333333333, 1, -0.333333333333333
    )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
`

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why you aggregate your data into means before doing the ANOVA, as an ANOVA is done on the raw data. This may very well be the reason why you do not get any p-values (and your results are neither valid nor interpretable).

Comment: Hi! I followed this "recipe" to do my analysis https://www.r-bloggers.com/2015/08/two-way-anova-with-repeated-measures/.

myData.mean then has the format as shown in the picture. Do you still have an idea how I could resolve it? 

``structure(list(PID12 = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Mode12 = c("V", 
"W", "V", "W", "V"), Task12 = c("CT", "MT", "CT", "MT", "CT"), 
    ER12 = c(2.33333333333333, 2, 0.333333333333333, 1, -0.333333333333333
    )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")``

This is part of the data. Again, thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that there is no p-value available in your case because your model is singular. If there would be a p-value available you could run the following code:

```
summary(stress.aov)[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][1]
```

Output:

```
NULL
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Do you have an idea why it is singular and how I could resolve it?
In the comments, I tried to put an excerpt of my data.

Comment: @Paul Bäumer, I would suggest check this post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11079/problem-with-anova-repeated-measures-error-model-is-singular

Comment: Thanks! I have gone through the article but still have issues resolving the problem. I tried it with the proposed code 'ezANOVA(data = myData.mean, wid=.(PID12), dv = .(ER12),
        within= .(Mode12, Task12))' but the only results I arrive at are errors :(..  From this I get the following error 'One or more cells is missing data.' although I don't think I have entered any missing data..

I also don't get the Error that my model is singular, so I feel really stuck :/